# Java constructor using generic types

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around Java generic types. Here's a simple piece of code that in my mind should work, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Eclipse reports this error in BreweryList.java:

```
The method breweryMethod() is undefined for the type <T>
```

The idea is to fill a Vector with instances of objects that are a subclass of the Brewery class, so the invocation would be something like:

```
BreweryList breweryList = new BreweryList(BrewerySubClass.class, list);
```

**BreweryList.java**

```
package com.beerme.test;

import java.util.Vector;

public class BreweryList<T extends Brewery> extends Vector<T> {
    public BreweryList(Class<T> c, Object[] j) {
        super();
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            T item = c.newInstance();

            // breweryMethod() is an instance method
            // of Brewery, of which <T> is a subclass (right?)

            c.breweryMethod();

            // "The method breweryMethod() is undefined
            // for the type <T>"
        }
    }
}
```

**Brewery.java**

```
package com.beerme.test;

public class Brewery {

    public Brewery() {
        super();
    }

    protected void breweryMethod() {
    }
}
```

**BrewerySubClass.java**

```
package com.beerme.test;

public class BrewerySubClass extends Brewery {
    public BrewerySubClass() {
        super();
    }

    public void brewerySubClassMethod() {
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is a complete-generics-noob question, but I'm stuck. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: A strongly suggest using your own `BreweryFactory` instead of abusing `Class`. If you can reasonably avoid reflection, do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ is much better for programming related questions.

Comment: I've seen this question few hours ago hear.

Comment: Are you sure the line "c.initBreweryFromObject();" isn't "item.initBreweryFromObject();"? Assuming so --

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
item.breweryMethod();
```

instead of

```
c.breweryMethod();
```

You were attempting to call the method on the `Class<T>`, not on the instance.

And actually, Eclipse reports

> The method breweryMethod() is undefined for the type Class<T>

and it should be clear from this message what has happened.

(And after you fix that, you will also have to handle the exceptions declared by `Class.newInstance()`)

As Tom Hawtin suggested in a comment, you'd better use a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead of using reflection in your method, in order to create your object.

Comment: Ach! You're right, of course: item instead of c. It compiles now after adding appropriate "throws" clauses.

I'll investigate factory methods. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Beer Me on SO it is a advisable to accept an answer which has worked for you (via the tick below the vote counter)

Answer (score 4):

Don't you mean:

```
item.breweryMethod();
```

instead of:

```
c.breweryMethod();
```

?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. The obvious mistakes are often the ones most difficult to see.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to answer your question: In the loop it should be `item.breweryMethod();` instead of `c.breweryMethod();`

I do not know what you plan to do, but it does not seem to be the best approach.
Here are some suggestions how you could improve your code:

- Replace `Vector` with `ArrayList` if you do not need the list to be synchronized
- Instead of extending a List implementation, consider *using* a list, or does your BreweryList provide more functionality than a standard list?

Comment: another +1 for the same reason

Comment: BreweryList will provide more functionality, as it's an interface between a remote MySQL database and a smartphone display. I'll take a look at ArrayList; that might in fact work better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the probable typo mention above... I don't see any such method `initBreweryFromObject()` defined anywhere in your sample code. This is the error then, no?